# Use text of text form for value of another?

Tags: html

I am fairly new to HTML and am having trouble figuring out this issue.

I have this form which lets the user enter their email address and then when they submit it registers them to the website.

I am wondering how can I get the value of the email address they enter for the value of another form?

Here's what I am working with. Any tips?:

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="https://register.sendreach.com/forms/?listid=7465"><input name="lid" value="7465" type="hidden">
<div class="field"><label>Email:</label>
<input class="text" name="email" value="My best email address is..." onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'My best email address is...';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'My best email address is...') {this.value = '';}" type="text">

<form action="http://mywebsite.com/?mode=register&amp;type=quick" method="post">
<input type="text" name="member_email" value = /></p>  **<--- Here is where I want to get the email address text used earlier in the name field called email and use it for the name field member_email. I want to use that as the value. How do I grab that?**

<input name="product_id" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="success_url" value="aHR0cDovL2luY29tZWphY2tlci5jb20vbWVtYmVyc2hpcC1ob21lLw==" type="hidden"></div>
<input class="button small_btn" value="Get Instant Access" type="submit">
<p class="small">Download Sent To Email!</p>
</form>
```

Comment: When you say "another form" do you mean you want to keep the information stored after the page is submitted and then reloads?

Comment: are you familiar with `jQUery?`

Comment: @Þaw: let’s keep this simple… he only tagged this HTML and is very new at HTML.

Comment: just asking though :D

Answer (score 0):

use sessions

page one:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['email_address']=$email_variable;
?>
```

page two:

```
<php
new_email_variable=$_SESSION['email_address'];
?>
```

Comment: Post didn’t mention PHP and isn’t tagged PHP. Furthermore your "page two" example won’t do anything.

Comment: 1st, it does matter. When you teach someone something new the syntax needs to be right.  2nd: He doesn’t need to know PHP in order to accomplish what he is asking. It can be accomplished in JavaScript or another server side language like Python or Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="https://register.sendreach.com/forms/?listid=7465"><input name="lid" value="7465" type="hidden">
<div class="field"><label>Email:</label>
<input class="text" name="email" value="My best email address is..." onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'My best email address is...';} document.getElementById('member_email').value=this.value;" onfocus="if (this.value == 'My best email address is...') {this.value = '';}" type="text">

<form action="http://mywebsite.com/?mode=register&amp;type=quick" method="post">
<input type="text" name="member_email" id="member_email"></p>  **<--- Here is where I want to get the email address text used earlier in the name field called email and use it for the name field member_email. I want to use that as the value. How do I grab that?**

<input name="product_id" value="1" type="hidden">
<input name="success_url" value="aHR0cDovL2luY29tZWphY2tlci5jb20vbWVtYmVyc2hpcC1ob21lLw==" type="hidden"></div>
<input class="button small_btn" value="Get Instant Access" type="submit">
<p class="small">Download Sent To Email!</p>
</form>
```

notice i have added id attribute to the input tage where you want to get the email address. and a little code in the tag from where you want to get the email address

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: @Phillip check my code by copy and pasting. it will work for him as he asked.

Answer (score 0):

Do something on submit (similar to how you're doing something on focus and on blur):

```
<form onsubmit="...
```

On the submit event, get the two email inputs:

```
var sourceInput = document.getElementsByName('email')[0];
var targetInput = document.getElementsByName('member_email')[0];
```

...and set the value:

```
targetInput.value = sourceInput.value;
```

I didn't test the above, but I believe that should do what you're looking for. It may be better to give the two inputs `id`s as well, so you can use `getElementById` instead of `getElementsByName`.

**Edit:**

The above would only work if both inputs and forms are on the same page, and also if the page is not refreshed. Based on the question, I am assuming that's the case. The above also does not check to see if the email was saved successfully (again, I don't know if that's something you want to check before copying the email over).